# How to create a file chooser without select option from cloud?

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-file, filechooser, android-fileprovider

Working with the task that selecting file from external storage.
Here my File chooser that shows the cloud selection options also like Google Drive and Drop-Box if it respective cloud application is available in device, that also displayed. **How to avoid file chooser that shows cloud selection option even if it is available in device.**

[image]

the above picture shows Google Drive as well as Drop-Box. How to avoid these Cloud options? and how to create File chooser that have only select option Device storage only.

I here by write my code that shows file chooser dialogue.

```
 private void showFileChooser1() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        Log.e("2", "2");
        try {
            Log.e("intent","intent"+intent.getType());
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),
                    FILE_SELECT_CODE);

        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
           }

    }
```

Comment: use a custom file chooser

Comment: could you please share any link or code. I searched about custom file chooser i didn't get the solution. Could you please help me to find the solution?

Comment: one thing, those are shown in your mobile not every mobile phone. since you opened some file from there, it shows some recent history when someone install your app, it isn't like your picture.

Comment: its a simple file chooser dialog example [Creating Custom File Explorer Dialog In Android](http://www.edumobile.org/android/creating-custom-file-explorer-dialog-in-android/)

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the many [file chooser libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35).

Or, create your own file chooser, using the Java `File` class and a suitable UI (e.g., `ListView`, `RecyclerView`) to navigate through directories and files.

`ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` are not tied to particular storage locations. Users can choose whatever content that they want. Usually, this is considered to be a good thing, as while *you* may not elect to use other storage providers, your *users* might.

Comment: Hey, any way to avoid all third party apps like `Gallery Sound Picker ES FileExploer` which are showing in above image? Like whatsapp?

Comment: @NileshDeokar: Use one of the many [file chooser libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35). Or, create your own file chooser, using the Java `File` class and a suitable UI (e.g., `ListView`, `RecyclerView`) to navigate through directories and files.

Comment: Hey.. Default chooser works fine for me. I just want to remove third party apps whatsapp opens default file chooser but we can not see third party apps in it.

Comment: @NileshDeokar: "Default chooser works fine for me" -- not according to your comments. "I just want to remove third party apps" -- then do not use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, as you do not control the UI of those options. "whatsapp opens default file chooser but we can not see third party apps in it" -- whatever MIME type they are requesting is not supported by those third-party apps, apparently.